# SvS for Verilog

Tags: verilog, vlsi, script

which is the best possible way to perform Schematic vs Schematic for 2 Verilog gate-level codes?

I want to do Svs just like people do for LvL in case of layout vs layout.
SvS is also available for spice netlist.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "performing Schematic vs Schematic"?

Comment: A schematic diagram is just a graphical representation of a netlist, so I don't understand what distinction you're making between the two of them.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumpation, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to what is called *formal equivalence checking*. When you make changes to a gate-level net-list to meet timing, loading, or any other optimization goals, an equivalence checker uses a symbolic proof to verify that the functionality remains the same. The proof is exhaustive, meaning there is no need to simulate with a set of tests.

See [this](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/formalpro/) for more info.

Comment: Also look up yosys for a free formal verification tool for verilog